# Can I check string to contain character that I didn't list?

Tags: java, string

To check whether a string contains a specific character you can use the `indexOf` method.

```
"Blah blah.".indexOf(".");  //Returns number
```

I have a string that should not contain anything but letters and numbers. I could check for that via regular expression:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
or just
[a-z\d]  /i
```

But in this particular case, regular expression is not welcome. In languages like C (or C++ for that matter), I'd instead loop the string through. As far as I know, in Java the `[]` operator is not an option for strings.

Is there an option that is faster than regexp?

Comment: What is a `[]` operator? Do you mean an array? Yes, `String` provides a `toCharArray()` method to get the underlying value (a copy of). You can iterate through those `char` values to detect an unwanted value.

Comment: if you dont want to use regex then you just gonna loop the String character by character

Comment: In C++, any *class* can implement `[]` operator to act as an array. `Vector`, C++'s version of `ArrayList` can be accessed via `vec[i]` instead of rather awkard `list.get(i)`.

Comment: @TomášZato Interesting. So, no, Java doesn't provide an indexer or whatever it is called. You'll need to go char by char either with the `toCharArray` or with `charAt(int)`.

Comment: toCharArray seems more promissing than `charAt`, which would probably consume lot's of cycles.

Comment: @TomášZato Well, `toCharArray` copies the full `char[]` that backs a `String`. `charAt` accesses it directly. So either you spend the time creating the new array or you spend the time invoking an extra method. It's negligible in either case, IMO.

Comment: Are you running into particular performance problems? Unless you're doing heavy-duty text processing, I seldom find that this level of optimization is worthwhile.

Comment: Well, the worst issue is the force of habit. But yes, there are many tiny strings (15 chars max) tu be checked. So I thought iterating through them may be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use String.indexOf:

```
boolean isLetterOrDigit(String s) {
    final String UPPERCASE_LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    final String LOWERCASE_LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    final String NUMBERS = "1234567890";
    final String ALLOWED = UPPERCASE_LETTERS 
    + LOWERCASE_LETTERS + NUMBERS;
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (ALLOWED.indexOf(ch) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing lots of validations in a tight inner loop and performance is a concern, one common pattern is to keep around a pre-compiled regex, e.g. as a static constant, to avoid the overhead of recompiling the same regex for each validation (as would be done in the convenience methods provided by `String`):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringValidate {
  private static final Pattern VALID_STR = Pattern.compile("(?i)[a-z0-9]+");

  public static boolean isValidStr(String s) {
    return VALID_STR.matcher(s).matches();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isValidStr("abc12d")); // true
    System.out.println(isValidStr("xyz "));   // false
  }
}
```

The advantage here is that you can easily tweak your validation rules over time by simply modifying the regex, with minimal code changes.

Comment: Actually, I always make regular expressions final. But it's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use regex via the `matches()` method to test:

```
if (!str.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")) {
    // str contains an unwanted char
```

FYI in java, regex flags are coded in the regex itself, so to implement your case insensitive example:

```
 if (!str.matches("(?i)[a-z0-9]+"))
```

Note also that `\d` is not equivalent to `[0-9]`, because it includes *all* digit characters (eg Arabic, Chinese, etc).

Comment: Apparently regex is not a desired.

Comment: Well, this way, it's readable at least... But I still hope for a byte-sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. There is a method called `String.contains(CharSequence s)` which can find any subsequence in a string. Hope it helps.

Comment: I take back what I said. You can loop through every single non-alphanumeric character and check that the string does not contain it, but that's really not a solution that should be used...